# Adding custom libraries to a Widget in ArcGIS Web AppAbuilder

Tags: javascript, jquery, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to add a local version of jquery and jquery-modal(https://jquerymodal.com/) to my widget and widget only, as it'll only be used in the widget.

I've tried making a folder called "extraLibs" in my widgets root folder (where widget.js/html are) and referencing it in widget.js in the define([]) and function() sections of the code, but i am doing it incorrectly as it returns a "jQuery is not defined" error so i believe the problem is in how i declare the .js files in the "extraLibs" folder.

I then went to https://jquerymodal.com/ and got the CDN links and downloaded both .js files, renaming them to jQuery.js and jQueryModal.js and placed them in the "extraLibs" folder.

I then declared them this way:

```
define([... './extraLibs/jQuery', './extraLibs/jQueryModal'],
function(... jQuery, jQueryModal){
//code goes here
});
```

It returns me the "jQuery is not defined" error in the console upon clicking the widget open.

I've tried according to this [thread](https://community.esri.com/thread/179507) with no luck.

What is the *proper* way to add external libs to widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully load jQuery in a widget level by doing the following:

```
define([... 'jimu/loaderplugins/jquery-loader!https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'],
function(...){
//code goes here
});
```

As for the jquery-modal module, i embedded it into widget.js directly in the postCreate function by moving its code over.

Answer (score 1):

Arcgis Web AppBuilder (WAB) defines **dojoConfing** variable inside init.js file. If you look closely, you will find a 'libs' package defined there:

```
...
,{
  name: "libs",
  location: window.path + "libs"
},
...
```

So, you could drop your external library inside the libs folder (wab/server/apps/1/libs/ - for an app with id 1) and then refer to that library using:

```
//File: MyWidget.js
define([
'libs/JQuery', 
'libs/lib2',
'libs/lib3'
],function(jQuery, Lib2, Lib3){
 //...
});
```

I didn't test this code, but judging by the WAB default widgets it seems the expected way to do it.

You can find more great tips on Web AppBuilder [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKEIvRlybC4).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the arcgis javascript api and therefore dojo then setup a dojoConfig object before including the dojo api.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var dojoConfig = {
aliases [
['jQuery', 'extraLibs/jquery/jquery.js'],
['jQueryModal', 'extraLibs/jquery-modal/jquery-modal.js']
]
}
</script>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/"></script>
```

then in your main javascript file you can  just reference the alias

```
define[... 'jQuery', 'jQueryModal],
function(... jQuery, jQueryModal){
});
```

Comment: Where would this dojoConfig would go? In the root of the widget? in the widget.html?

Comment: Another question i have: Do the .js files need to be in separate folders?

Comment: you would include the dojoConfig in a script tag in your main html file before including the arcgis library. The .js files don't need to be anywhere in particular.

Comment: I'm trying to add a library to the widget inside an application without having the librabries mess with the rest of the application in WAB. I want only the widget to have this functionality.

I've tried doing it according to this thread: https://community.esri.com/thread/179507 with no luck. It returns script errors.

Comment: you should make sure that you're paths are right. The dojo loader may not consider root, what you think root is.